# How do I indicate to CoreData that an object has changed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios7

In my CoreData model, I have an entity called Contact. It has an attribute called `profileImage`, with the type set to Transformable.

In the Contact class (a subclass of NSManagedObject), I've changed profileImage from being a generic id to being an UploadedImage:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UploadedImage * profileImage;
```

The UploadedImage class has a few properties of its own.

The problem is that CoreData doesn't know when the properties on the UploadedImage object have changed. If only those properties are changed, the `willSave` method is never called on the Contact object when the managed object is saved. It works as expected if I change any other property on the Contact object: it just doesn't "see" changes to anything on the UploadedImage object within the Contact object.

What's the correct way to indicate that the managed object needs to be saved? Should I manually call `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` for the key 'profileImage' on my Contact object?

**Edit to clarify a couple things**

- Contact is a CoreData entity, but the ImageUpload class is NOT.
- CoreData *will* save the data in the ImageUpload object (because I implemented the `NSCoding` protocol methods, I think). If I change a property on the ImageUpload object, AND change a property on the Contact object, the Contact is saved, and that changed value persists on the ImageUpload object when the Contact is loaded from CoreData again.

Comment: Is the subclass also a entity in your core data Schema?

Comment: No, the subclass is not an entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there's another way I'm not aware of, it sounds like marking the `NSManagedObject` as dirty is the way to go. You can do that using a separate `dirtyFlag` attribute, or by simply using the `profileImage` attribute itself.

One way to automate this would be KVO. You observe all properties of `UploadedImage` in the `Contact` class, and then just call `self.profileImage = self.profileImage`. I'm not sure if this is optimized by the compiler. If it is, you can also call `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:`, which should trigger it. If Core Data noticed that the object didn't actually change, you can try to implement `NSCopying` and assign a copy of the original `UploadedImage`.

Comment: I wound up using your last option: implemented `NSCopying`, and convince the object it's dirty by using `self.profileImage = [self.profileImage copy];` Thanks!

Comment: @BrockBoland: Out of curiosity, did you use KVO or another mechanism?

Comment: Sort of a poor-man's KVO. I needed to be able to get and set values from a top-level object using something like valueForKey: and setValue:forKey: but recursively, so I wrote a category to add methods like those but a bit more flexible: https://github.com/brockboland/NSObject-KeyDotValue

Then, I overrode changeValue:forProperty: to do that copy when a particular key is set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Core Data will persist changes made to the subclass. The contract in Core data is between the parent entity and Core Data, so Core Data only responds to changes made to the properties in the entity class.

You can get around this by making that property a `NSDictionary` in the Entity and in the subclass add the image object to the dictionary.

Comment: I edited my original question to note that the data on the non-entity ImageUpload object will persist, as long as changes on the Contact entity trigger the save.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon Scott's solution (no copy necessary!), here is a method for Swift that works with any field:

```
static func markDirty<C, T>(_ obj: C, _ keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<C, T>) {
    obj[keyPath: keyPath] = obj[keyPath: keyPath]
}
```

Used like so:

```
NSManagedObject.markDirty(playlist, \.rules)
```

Unfortunately it's not possible right now to define it as an instance method, due to limitations with generics.